# Stream filter produce different outcome from static call reference compared to object method call

Tags: java, java-stream

I had the following part of code:

```
permissionsType.getGranteeCapabilities().stream()
        .filter(g -> g.getCapabilities() != null &&
                     g.getCapabilities().getCapability() != null)
```

and I wanted to extracted in a method like below:

```
public boolean isPermissionWithCapabilities(Capabilities g) {
    return g.getCapabilities() != null &&
           g.getCapabilities().getCapability() != null;
}

permissionsType.getGranteeCapabilities().stream()
            .filter(object::isPermissionWithCapabilities)
```

When I declared the method the outcome despite the input was always false but when I declared the method as static the outcome was computed correctly.

```
public static boolean isPermissionWithCapabilities(Capabilities g) {
    return g.getCapabilities() != null &&
           g.getCapabilities().getCapability() != null;
}

permissionsType.getGranteeCapabilities().stream()
        .filter(DashboardUserPermissionService::isPermissionWithCapabilities)
```

I cannot understand why the same method with just the `static` word behaves differently. Any ideas?

Comment: What does mean object::isPermissionWithCapabilities in your case? what is object?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows that the filter always return `false`.

Comment: if you change in non static way filter predicate to -> .filter(capability -> isPermissionWithCapabilities(capability)) or .filter(this::isPermissionWithCapabilities) it should work correct and return same results as static way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intention correctly, then you need to declare parameterless instance method in the class to which stream elements belong.

Like that:

```
public class DashboardUserPermissionService {
    private Capabilities capabilities;

    public boolean isPermissionWithCapabilities() {
        return capabilities != null && getCapabilities.getCapability() != null;
    }
}
```

That would allow expessing your predicate with a method reference:

```
DashboardUserPermissionService::isPermissionWithCapabilities
```

Also you might consider making the names a bit more concise.

Comment: @Bobulous No, it wouldn't. In this case, it would be a [Reference to an Instance Method of a Particular Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#object). Example `filter(Collection::isEmpty())` which is an equivalent of a predicate expressed with a lambda expression `filter(c -> c.isEmpty())` (you can easily test both).